# Extjs adding multiple items to a window does not work

Tags: extjs

I have a panel defined like this:

```
var msgDetailsPanel = new Ext.ux.ManagedIFrame.Panel({
    title: 'M',
    header: true,
    width:700,
    height:200,
    autoScroll: true
});
```

And I have a Grid defined like this:

```
var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id:'detailGrid',
    store: dataStore,
    collapsible: false,
    columnLines: false,
    enableHdMenu: false,
    header: false,
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            sortable: true
        },
        {id:'msgId',hidden: true, dataIndex: 'msgId'},                    
        {sortable: true, dataIndex: 'deliveryAddr'},
        {sortable: true, dataIndex: 'deliveryDate'},
        {sortable: true, dataIndex: 'status', renderer:function(value, p, record){
            return String.format( '<font color="009966">{0}</font>', value );}},
        {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick = "alert({msgId})">View Message Details</a>'}  
    }),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit:true
    },
    columnLines: false,
    frame:false,
    collapsible: false,
    animCollapse: false,
    title: alertName,
    disableSelection: true,
    deferRowRender:false
});
```

Now  I want to add these two components to a window.

```
win = new Ext.Window({
    layout:'fit', 
    title: '<spring:message code="title.alertDetails" />',
    autoDestroy: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    width:600,
    height:400,
    closable:false,
    plain: true,
    items: [{detailGrid}, {msgDetailsPanel}],//This is where error comes
    buttons: [{
        text: '<spring:message code="label.button.close" />',
        handler: function(){
            win.hide(this);
        }
    }]
});
```

I get error:
Expected ':'
When I am adding only the `msgDetailsPanel` under `items`, things work fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
items: [{detailGrid}, {msgDetailsPanel}],
```

with:

```
items: [detailGrid, msgDetailsPanel],
```