# Updating a managed iframe panel in extjs

Tags: extjs

Aplogies for a long post. This is a continuation of the question:
[Extjs adding multiple items to a window does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262524/extjs-adding-multiple-items-to-a-window-does-not-work/7262564#7262564)
In the question, I had a grid defined like this:

```
var updater = msgDetailsPanel.getUpdater();/*Added new*/


var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
id:'detailGrid',
store: dataStore,
collapsible: false,
columnLines: false,
enableHdMenu: false,
header: false,
cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
defaults: {
sortable: true
},
{id:'msgId',hidden: true, dataIndex: 'msgId'},                  
{sortable: true, dataIndex: 'deliveryAddr'},
{sortable: true, dataIndex: 'deliveryDate'},
{sortable: true, dataIndex: 'status', renderer:function(value, p, record){
return String.format( '<font color="009966">{0}</font>', value );}},
{header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick = "alert({msgId})">View Message Details</a>'}  
]
}),
viewConfig: {
forceFit:true
},
columnLines: false,
frame:false,
collapsible: false,
animCollapse: false,
title: alertName,
disableSelection: true,
deferRowRender:false
});
```

I wish to replace `onClick = "alert({msgId})"` with `onClick = "updater.update({msgId})"` So that on click of the hyperlink 'View Message Details', the Panel will be populated with the msgId.
But I get:

```
javascript error: this.ds.fields.get(...).name is null or not an object.
```

How can  i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your ID ('msgId') is hardcoded, I suggest a simple tack:

```
Ext.onReady( function()
{
    // When the DOM is ready, establish a handler (onClick) for the msgId node.
    // Again, msgId is hardcoded - not certain why you would pass it as a parameter to updater - 
    // but createDelegate passes msgId as a parameter.
    Ext.get('msgId').on( 'click', updater.update.createDelegate( this, [{msgId}], 0 ))
});
```

Comment: I like to create all DOM IDs using Ext.id.  Essentially it means never caring about the exact value of a DOM ID - e.g. Ext.id( null, 'something').  It also means your code will never have something like id:'msgId' - a hardcoded ID.